# Minimal set of invariants to specify a Kepler orbit

Tags: orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics, degrees-of-freedom, invariants, laplace-runge-lenz-vector

In the [Kepler problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler_problem), we know that there are various invariants, including:

- Energy
- Angular momentum vector
- Runge-Lenz vector

All together these consist of 7 parameters.  On the other hand, the [orbital elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_elements) consist of only 6 parameters, and one of them (the mean anomaly) is just a time reference, so if we ignore time offsets there are only 5 parameters needed to describe an orbit.

So there should be some relationships among the invariants so that there are only 5 degrees of freedom.

The angular momentum vector and Runge-Lenz vector have to be perpendicular.  So if I specify these two vectors, that's 5 degrees of freedom.  Does that fully specify the orbit?  Can the energy be calculated from them?

What about if I specify the angular momentum and the energy?  That's only 4 degrees of freedom; what else is needed?

What if I specify the Runge-Lenz vector and the energy?  Again, it's only 4 degrees of freedom, so what's the last component needed to nail down the orbit?

Comment: The energy doesn't do you any good, it's proportional to the mass of the object, but we already know that orbits are independent of the mass.

Comment: @CuriousOne The energy definitely varies from one orbit to another (keeping the orbiting object's mass fixed), so I don't think it's true that it doesn't do you any good. To factor out the masses of different objects, you could use "energy per unit mass" instead.

Comment: Yes, energy per mass can be used as a specification, but that was not what you were asking. Just wanted to make sure you are aware of that.

Comment: There are indeed two relationships between the seven conserved quantities, cf. this [Wikipedia entry](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%E2%80%93Runge%E2%80%93Lenz_vector#Constants_of_motion_and_superintegrability).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct, that there must be 5 independent constants of the motion, allowing closed 1-dimensional orbits in the 6-dimensional phase space.  I'll show now that from the LRL vector, $\textbf{A}$, you can get only one additional conserved quantity.

The magnitude of $\textbf{A}$, depending on scaling can be chosen to correspond to the eccentricity of the orbit $e$.  This can be found from the orbital energy and angular momentum through
$$e=\sqrt{1+ \frac{2 E h^2}{\mu^2}}.$$

Hence the magnitude of the LRL vector can contribute no additional constant of the motion, and we must look at its direction.  Through the definition
$$\textbf{A} = \textbf{p}\times\textbf{L}-mk \hat{\textbf{r}},$$
we see that $\textbf{A}$ must be perpendicular to $\textbf{L}$, as
$$\textbf{A}\cdot \textbf{L} =\textbf{L}\cdot \left( \textbf{p}\times\textbf{L}\right)- \textbf{L}\cdot \left( mk \hat{\textbf{r}}\right) = \textbf{p}\cdot\left( \textbf{L} \times \textbf{L} \right) - mk \left( \textbf{p}\cdot (\hat{\textbf{r}}\times \textbf{r})\right) = 0,$$
where I've cyclically permuted the scalar triple products, to show they must both identically vanish.  This statement, is that $\textbf{A}\cdot \textbf{L}=0$, or that $\textbf{A}$ lies in the plane of motion of the orbit.  Since $\textbf{A}$ is constrained to lie in a plane already specified by the angular momentum, $\textbf{A}$ can only contribute one extra independent conserved quantity, namely the direction it points in the plane of the orbit.  You can show that $\textbf{A}$ in fact points along the symmetry axis that all Keplerian orbits possess.

So we have shown $\textbf{A}$ can only contribute a single additional conserved quantity.  We get a conserved quantity from energy, and 3 conserved quantities from angular momentum, giving us a total of 5 conserved quantities.